# Desconto com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, funções

Fiz um JavaScript para calcular descontos de um determinado valor, mas acho que ele não está calculando a porcentagem de forma correta. Se alguém poder me ajudar, eu agradeço!

1. Pagando em débito a pessoa ganha 25% de desconto;
2. Pagando no crédito sem parcelas ganha 20% de desconto;
3. Pagando parcelado a pessoa ganha 5% de desconto;

Acredito que os valores das porcentagens que coloquei no js estão errados pois não está calculando da forma correta. O do crédito parcelado dá um valor absurdo!

obs: como colocaria esses descontos apenas para valores acima de 99.99?

```js
function calcular(){
 var x = document.getElementById("valor");
 var pagar = document.getElementById("pagar");
 var d = document.getElementById("debito");
 var parc = document.getElementById("parcelado");
 var semp = document.getElementById("semparcelas");
  var p = Number(x.value);
  var y = p;
  var s=0;
   if(parc.checked){
    y = (y*0.5);
    s= p-y;
   }
   if(semp.checked){
    y = (y*0.20);
    s= p-y;
   }
   if(d.checked){
    y = (y*0.25);
    s= p-y;
   }
 pagar.value= "Desconto: "+y+". Pagar: "+s;
}
```

```html
<label for="valor"> Digite o valor da compra: </label>
<br>
<input type="text" id="valor" name="valor" required onfocus="fn(this)" onblur="fs(this)">
<br>
<br> Qual sua forma de pagamento?
<br>
<input type="radio" name="pagamento" id="debito" value="debito">
<label for="debito"> Débito </label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="pagamento" id="parcelado" value="parcelado">
<label for="parcelado"> Crédito parcelado </label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="pagamento" id="semparcelas" value="semparcelas">
<label for="semparcelas"> Crédito sem parcelas</label>
<br></br>
Desconto e valor a pagar:
<br>
<input type="text" id="pagar" name="pagar" disabled>
<input id="botao1" type="button" value="Calcular" onclick="calcular()" onmouseover="botao(this)" onmouseout="botao(this)">
```

Comment: Aqui os valores estão corretos. Porque acha que não está funcionando? Consegue [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/271554/edit) a pergunta e colocar o que está ocasionando os valores errados?

Comment: Por algum  motivo, o crédito parcelado está dando um valor maior em desconto em relação aos outros, sendo que deveria ser ao contrário. Talvez eu tenha usado os valores ao contrário, você poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Você está dando 50% de desconto. A linha exata é `y = (y*0.5);`. Talvez você tenha que revisar seu código, principalmente nas "regras de 3" da sua programação. De qualquer forma sua pergunta está marcada como pendente pois não está claro o suficiente na pergunta. De quanto exatamente deveria ser o desconto?

Comment: Editei a pergunta. Deveria ser de 25%, 20% e 5%

Comment: `*0.5` é `50%` ... `5%` é  `*0.05`

Comment: Exatamente como Leandro falou mude esse trecho: `y = (y*0.05);`

Answer (score 3):

Primeiramente altere o cálculo do pagamento parcelado de:

```
valor * 0.5 //50% do valor.
```

Para:

```
valor * 0.05 //5% do valor.
```

Segundo, evite o uso de variáveis como `x, y, z` isso dificulta a leitura e manutenção do código, tente utilizar nomes que sugiram o que a variável contém.

Por último para aplicar o desconto somente para valores acima de 99.9 basta adicionar a condição:

```
if(valor>99.9){
   //lógica...
}
```

Segue exemplo abaixo:

```js
function calcular(){
 var valor             = document.getElementById("valor").value;
 var resultado         = document.getElementById("pagar");
 var debito            = document.getElementById("debito");
 var creditoParcelado  = document.getElementById("parcelado");
 var credito           = document.getElementById("semparcelas");
  var desconto          = 0;
  
  if(valor>99.9){
    if(creditoParcelado.checked){
      desconto = valor*0.05; //5%
      valor = valor*0.95;

    }

    if(credito.checked){
      desconto = valor*0.20;
      valor = valor*0.80;
    }

    if(debito.checked){
      desconto = valor*0.25;
      valor = valor*0.75
    }
  }
  
 resultado.value = "Desconto: "+desconto+". Pagar: "+valor;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <label for="valor"> Digite o valor da compra: </label> <br>
  <input type="text" id="valor" name="valor" required>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Qual sua forma de pagamento?</p>
  <input type="radio" name ="pagamento" id="debito" value="debito"> 
  <label for="debito"> Débito </label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="pagamento" id="parcelado" value="parcelado"> 
  <label for="parcelado"> Crédito parcelado </label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="pagamento" id="semparcelas" value="semparcelas"> 
  <label for="semparcelas"> Crédito sem parcelas</label>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Desconto e valor a pagar: </p>
  <input type="text" id="pagar" name="pagar">
  <input id="botao1" type="button" value="Calcular" onclick="calcular()">
</div>
```